# C# LINQ dynamic Query translate to stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, stored-procedures

I'm new to SQL and trying to translate a C# linq query to a stored procedure.

The Linq query looks like this:

```
if (subscription.address1 != null) 
   address1 = subscription.CountryNames.Split(new string[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList();

if (subscription.address2 != null) 
   address2= subscription.CountryNames.Split(new string[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList();

var query = context
               .Information
               .Where(item => item.AppearanceDate >= dateFromDT && item.AppearanceDate <= dateToDT);

if (address1.Count > 0)
    query = query.Where(item => address1.Contains(item.address1));

if (address2.Count > 0)
    query = query.Where(item =>  address2.Contains(item.address2));

var results = query.select.toList()
```

Table name: **Information**

Columns:

```
Person_Name
address1
address2
```

`address2` and `address1` are passed in

How do I write a stored procedure for this?

Must I create a `#Temp` table for each address and query from? Thanks in advance

Comment: Procedural code is **highly vendor-specific** - so please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely. Also: it would be **extremely helpful** to know what your table structure looks like - what tables and columns are you dealing with?

Comment: @marc_s my bad, Its sql-server, this is just an example TABLE :**Information** and Columns:**address1**,**address2**,**address3**,**address4**.

Comment: What do those columns link to - please **update** your question and provide the **complete** structure for **all tables** involved here!

Comment: We **still don't know** what **datatypes** those columns are ..... and are those just simple columns, or do they link (as foreign keys) to another table? If so: **what table** and what is its structure?

Comment: @marc_s No those are **simple columns** and not linked to any key, i'm not following you. **data type string**. my main Questing is how i do these lines if (address1.Count > 0)
    query = query.Where(item => address1.Contains(item.address1));

if (address2.Count > 0)
    query = query.Where(item =>  address2.Contains(item.address2)); in var results = query.select.toList()

Comment: What I don't yet understand is that "subscription" entity and how you're creating the "address1" etc. values........ not clear at all

Comment: subscription is just a class which i'm getting address1 and address2 which list<string>datatypes. so if list address 1 contains values then i must query Information where "address1 list* conatins *address1 column* so the table **Information** has values. @marc_s